# Adhesive for use with a foam liner under the door panel

Tags: door

I recently pulled a door panel to fix a broken cable.  There was a foam liner behind the panel that had to come off to access the cable.  I think this serves as a water barrier, so I want to make sure it stays on when I put it back on.  The existing adhesive has seen better days.  What adhesive should I use?  What is the proper term for the foam sheet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use [spray trim adhesive](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0002JMPRA) as a first choice, it adheres very well and I have used it for such jobs. If I didn't have that available, I'd use [gorilla glue](http://www.homedepot.com/buy/paint/adhesives-tape/gorilla-glue/2-oz-interior-and-exterior-all-purpose-adhesive-54287.html) for its waterproof and expanding properties (though a little more hassle than I'd like to put into it), or as a third option general spray adhesive.

Comment: +1 for trim adhesive.  Doesn't have to be spray if you don't like spray, they make regular liquid trim adhesive too.

Comment: I saw that when I searched for it, but I've never used it so I specified the spray kind. Good to know!

Answer (score 3):

I am only 7+ years late, maybe this will help someone else.

1. The foam peace between the door and the "Door trim panel" is called the "Water Deflector"
2. The black glue is very close to "3M strip caulk" or "Dum Dum caulk.  They both remain soft and sticky. Unless you get it dirty or tear it up getting the deflector off, you can usually use it (the calk and the deflector) over and over again.  Anything else and you may be buying a $65.00 deflector if it ever needs to come off again.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Thanks for the answer! Even if it's late, it's good information to be able to share with others. :)

Comment: I just wanted to say thank you to the guy who answered 7+ late, the post was very helpful and well worth the effort you put in!